# How to use one import statement instead of multiple using react and javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am using two import statements for importing from another file.

below is the import statements.

```
import {TITLE AS TI} from '../constants';
import {Username, Password} from '../constants';
```

As you see from above code, i am importing TITLE, Username, Password from constants file
how can put these two import statements to one.

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: `import {TITLE as TI, Username, Password} from '../constants';`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as a single import. See the below snippet

**Constants.js**

```
export const TITLE = "Test Title";
export const username = "johndoe";
export const password = "test";
```

**App.js**

```
import { TITLE as TI, username, password } from "./Constants";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      {TI}
      <p>
        <b>username</b>: {username}
      </p>
      <p>
        <b>password</b>: {password}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```